# Church encoding conversion function fails to compile with GADTs

Tags: haskell, gadt, church-encoding

The `to_c` function below is rejected due to a type error when compiling with the GADTs extension that I want to use for an unrelated code fragment that is not shown here.

```
newtype Church = Church { unC :: forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a }
to_c :: Int -> Church
to_c 0 = let f0 f c = c in Church f0
to_c n =
    let fn f c = iterate f c !! n in Church fn
```

Error message:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a0’ with ‘a’ because type variable ‘a’ would escape its scope
  This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
    a type expected by the context:
      (a -> a) -> a -> a

  Expected type: (a -> a) -> a -> a
    Actual type: (a0 -> a0) -> a0 -> a0
  In the first argument of ‘Church’, namely ‘fn’
```

I can rewrite the function in direct recursive style that will type check and also work; however, I was curious as to why this iterative approach is defective and whether it can be salvaged with some clever type annotations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really doesn't have anything to do with GADTs, only, the `-XGADTs` extension also implies `-XMonoLocalBinds`, and that's the real problem here. What it does is, because the local binding `fn` has no explicit signature it wants to give it a type that is no more polymorphic than the environment... i.e. in this case *not polymorphic at all*. But of course, it *must* be polymorphic so it can actually be used in the `Church` type, so that's no good.

You can still give an *explicit* polymorphic signature:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, MonoLocalBinds #-}
newtype Church = Church { unC :: forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a }
to_c :: Int -> Church
-- to_c 0 = ...  -- the base case is redundant.
to_c n =
    let fn :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
        fn f c = iterate f c !! n
    in Church fn
```

but an easier solution is to just don't make any *binding* at all, then `-XMonoLocalBinds` doesn't come into play:

```
to_c :: Int -> Church
to_c n = Church (\f c -> iterate f c !! n)
```

...or, if you do make a binding, do it within the `Church` constructor, because there the environment is already polymorphic:

```
to_c n = Church (let fn f c = iterate f c !! n in fn)
```

Comment: `MonoLocalBinds` looks quite restrictive in this case, especially because the local binding does not really involve GADTs. I wonder if a more relaxed approach could be used by GHC.

Comment: @chi, maybe. But it's important for users to be able to predict when inference will succeed. `MonoLocalBinds` is already a bit hard to understand (because it tries to allow polymorphism sometimes); getting more clever sounds risky.